# How to put an Array into an ArrayList of Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Recently I was using the ArrayLists. Now I have to do this exercise where I have to put an array into an **ArrayList of arrays**.

```
ArrayList<int[]> cartelle = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

This is the ArrayList of arrays, now I have to put the below array in it

```
cartella = new int[NUMERICARTELLA];
```

both have to be filled with int.

I tried to use `Arrays.asList()` but I don't think is the right solution.
I tried to fill it as `giocatori.get(i).setCartelle(cartella)` but the compiler suggest me to convert the array in an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `add()` method, which adds a new element at the end of the list - it'll be at index 0, because the list was empty:

```
ArrayList<int[]> cartelle = new ArrayList<>();
cartelle.add(new int[NUMERICARTELLA]);
```

To retrieve the array, use the `get()` method:

```
int[] array = cartelle.get(0);
```

After you've added an element, you can replace it with the `set()` method:

```
cartelle.set(0, new int[NUMERICARTELLA]);
```

Those three methods will get you started, for more details and lots of additional methods check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

An array is still an object so you can put it in an `ArrayList` like any other object.  Here are some examples:

Using `List.of`

```
List<int[]> list = List.of(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{3,4,6});
for (int[] arr : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 6]
```

Using `Arrays.asList()`

```
List<int[]> list2 = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{3,4,6});
for (int[] arr : list2) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 6]
```

Iterating over a "2D" array and adding to a list

```
int[][] arrs = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
List<int[]> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int[] arr : arrs) {
    list3.add(arr);
}

for (int[] arr : list3) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```